# Prevent CollectionView from filling parent

Tags: iphone, ios

My collection view fills the entire view. How can i make it keep the size it have in the storyboard designer? See picture.

[image]

Comment: What class are you using in the storyboard? Is it a UICollectionViewController or just a UIViewController with a UICollectionView added to it.

Comment: It is a UICollectionView in a UIViewController

Comment: Did you hook up the collectionView to an IBOutlet and set the collectionViewControllers' view to that outlet? Looks like you pushed the collectionViewsControllers view to the UIViewControllers view.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. I removed that outlet and it removed the fill. Although now it is really tiny. It is full width but the height is like 30px: http://i.imgur.com/yO9oG.png

Comment: Also, you should post that as an answer